# redux toolkit query,unable to return value with with transformResponse using queryFn

Tags: typescript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I would like to modify the response received from the backend with the transformResponse function but I get an error even when I only return the first argument ""baseQueryReturnValue"".

```
export const categoryApiSlice = createApi({
    reducerPath: "Categories",
    baseQuery: fakeBaseQuery(),
    tagTypes: ["CategoriesTag"],
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getAllCategories: builder.query<Category[], void>({
            async queryFn() {
                try {
                    const ref = collection(db, "categories");
                    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(ref);
                    let categories: Category[] = [];
                    querySnapshot?.forEach((doc) => {
                        categories.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() } as Category);
                    });

                    return { data: categories };
                } catch (error: any) {
                    console.error(error.message);
                    return { error: error.message };
                }
            },

        ///// here i'm getting the error pasted below //////
            transformResponse(baseQueryReturnValue, meta, arg) {
                return baseQueryReturnValue
            },


            providesTags: ["CategoriesTag"],
        }),
 
    }),
});

export const { useGetAllCategoriesQuery } = categoryApiSlice;
```

here is the type script error
Type '(baseQueryReturnValue: unknown, meta: {}, arg: void) => unknown' is not assignable to type '(baseQueryReturnValue: unknown, meta: {}, arg: void) => Category[] | Promise<Category[]>'.
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Category[] | Promise<Category[]>'.ts(2322)
endpointDefinitions.d.ts(54, 5): The expected type comes from property 'transformResponse' which is declared here on type 'OmitFromUnion<QueryDefinition<void, BaseQueryFn, "CategoriesTag", Category[], "Categories">, "type">'

I also tried not to use transformResponse but rather to modify the response received in the queryFn but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`transformResponse` exists because when you use the `query` argument to a query definition, you only create the input to your `baseQuery` and have no control over what happens afterwards. If only `query`, but not `transformResponse`, existed, you had no control over the final return value.

Now, when you use `queryFn`, you have full control over the final return value already - you write the full `queryFn` function after all, and you can do any kind of transformation inside of it already.

That's why **`transformResponse` only works with `query`, but *doesn't exist* as an option when you use `queryFn`**.
It's not necessary in that context and would only split up your logic instead of keeping it in one place.

=> You cannot use `transformResponse` and `queryFn` at the same time. It doesn't make sense, so it's not possible.
Do your transformation inside of `queryFn` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `transformResponse` has to be an `ResultType | Promise<ResultType>`  but baseQueryReturnValue is of type `BaseQueryResult<BaseQuery>`
(https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#query-endpoint-definition)

```js
     transformResponse(baseQueryReturnValue, meta, arg) {
         return baseQueryReturnValue.result.post
     }
```

Comment: according to your answer and your link I found this thank you
/* transformResponse only available with `query`, not `queryFn` */
  transformResponse?(
    baseQueryReturnValue: BaseQueryResult<BaseQuery>,
    meta: BaseQueryMeta<BaseQuery>,
    arg: QueryArg,
  ): ResultType | Promise<ResultType>